# ChartJS multiple datasets but with single bar chart

Tags: chart.js

I need a bar chart using two different datasets because one is for the volume and the other is for the euro. The problem is that I just need the first bar to use the volume values and 4 others to use the euro value, but if I use two datasets the bars will be displayed two by two and I need only one per every x value. If I don't but values trying to skip some parts in the array it will be show with a lot of space and I need it to be good to see..
Thank you for your help, for now my code is this:

```
var blocked = new Array(false,false,false,false); //bloccare o no una delle 4 barre

const data = {
  labels: ['Volume', 'Manutenzione', 'Professionals', 'Materie', 'Cleaning'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Volumi',
    data: [60000, 10000, 20000, 25000, 15000],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
      'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
      'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
      'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
      'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1,
    dragData: true,
    pointHitRadius: 20, //allargare la presa a 20px così non devi essere preciso a pigliarla
  },
  {
    label: 'euro',
    data:[,500000,200000,300000,100000],
    yAxisID: "y1"
  }
  ]
};



// config 
const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
      plugins:{
        //tooltip:{ //rimuovere il tooltip
        //  enabled: false
        //},
        dragData: {
            
            round: 1, //round data, 0 per essere intero
            //magnet: {
                //to: Math.round, //far diventare il valore all'intero più vicino
                //to: (value) => value + 2 questo lo fa diventare + 2
            //},
            onDragStart: (event) =>{
                //console.log(event)
                var labl = getLabel(event)
                
                
                
                switch(labl){
                    case "Manutenzione": 
                        blocked[0] = !blocked[0];
                        return false;
                    case "Professionals": 
                        blocked[1] = !blocked[1];
                        return false ;
                    case "Materie": 
                        blocked[2] = !blocked[2];
                        return false ;
                    case "Cleaning": 
                        blocked[3] = !blocked[3];
                        return false ;
                    default: return true
                }
                //event.target.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
            },
            onDrag:(event, datasetIndex, index, value) =>{
                event.target.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
                updateValues(value)
            },
            onDragEnd:(event, datasetIndex, index, value) =>{
                //console.log(event)
                event.target.style.cursor = 'default';
            }
        }
      },
        scales: {
          y: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: 120000,
            beginAtZero: true,
            min: 0,
            grid:{
                drawOnChartArea: false
            }
          },
          y1: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: 1000000,
            beginAtZero: true,
            min: 0,
            position: 'right'
          }
        }
  }
};

// render init block
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);



function updateValues(val){
    var vol = myChart.data.datasets[0].data[0] //volume
    var man = myChart.data.datasets[0].data[1] //manutenzione
    var prof = myChart.data.datasets[0].data[2] //professionals
    var mat = myChart.data.datasets[0].data[3] //materie
    var clean = myChart.data.datasets[0].data[4] //cleaning
        
    var tot4 = man + prof + mat + clean
    var diff = vol - tot4
    var diff2 = diff/4
    
    if(!blocked[0])man+=diff2
    if(!blocked[1])prof+=diff2
    if(!blocked[2])mat+=diff2
    if(!blocked[3])clean+=diff2
    
        
    update(man, prof, mat, clean)
    
}

function update(man, prof, mat, clean){
    
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data[1] = man
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data[2] = prof
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data[3] = mat
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data[4] = clean

    myChart.update()

}

function getLabel(evt) {
    const points = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);

    if (points.length) {
        const firstPoint = points[0];
        const label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
        //console.log(label)
        return label
    }
}

function clickHandler(evt) {
    const points = myChart.getElementsAtEventForMode(evt, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);

    if (points.length) {
        const firstPoint = points[0];
        const label = myChart.data.labels[firstPoint.index];
        const value = myChart.data.datasets[firstPoint.datasetIndex].data[firstPoint.index];
        //console.log(label)
        return label
    }
}


function mousemoveHandler(mousemove, chart){
    //console.log(mousemove)
    
    const cursorPosition = chart.getElementsAtEventForMode(mousemove, 'nearest', {intersect: true}, true)

    //console.log(cursorPosition)
    if(cursorPosition[0]){ //se c'è almeno un el
        const label = myChart.data.labels[cursorPosition[0].index];
            mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'default';
            
                switch(label){
                    case "Volume":
                        mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'grab';
                        break;
                    case "Manutenzione": 
                        if(blocked[0]) mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'move'; 
                        else mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'not-allowed'; 
                        break;
                    case "Professionals": 
                        if(blocked[1]) mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'move'; 
                        else mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'not-allowed'; 
                        break;
                    case "Materie": 
                        if(blocked[2]) mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'move'; 
                        else mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'not-allowed'; 
                        break;
                    case "Cleaning": 
                        if(blocked[3]) mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'move'; 
                        else mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'not-allowed'; 
                        break;
                    default: console.log("qui non ci entrerà mai")
                        mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'default';
                }
            //mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'default';
        
    }
    else    mousemove.target.style.cursor = 'default';
}

myChart.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    mousemoveHandler(e, myChart)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a tricky use case. I'm adding a snippet where you have 1 dataset per data (and not only 2). The data are stored in the datasets by a data point. There are the definition of X axes as well in order to avoid the behavior for category+bar chart.

```js
const data = {
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Volumi',
    data: [{x: 1, y: 60000}],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    xAxisID: "x1",
    categoryPercentage: 1
  },
  {
    label: 'euro',
    data:[{x: 2, y: 500000}],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    xAxisID: "x1",
    yAxisID: "y1",
    categoryPercentage: 1
  },
  {
    label: 'euro',
    data:[{x: 3, y: 200000}],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    xAxisID: "x1",
    yAxisID: "y1",
    categoryPercentage: 1
  },
  {
    label: 'euro',
    data:[{x: 4, y: 300000}],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    xAxisID: "x1",
    yAxisID: "y1",
    categoryPercentage: 1
  },
  {
    label: 'euro',
    data:[{x: 5, y: 100000}],
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
    borderWidth: 1,
    xAxisID: "x1",
    yAxisID: "y1",
    categoryPercentage: 1
  }
  ]
};

const config = {
  type: 'bar',
  data,
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: false,
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          title(tooltipItems){
            if (tooltipItems.length) {
              const item = tooltipItems[0];
              const tick = item.chart.scales.x.ticks[item.datasetIndex]; 
              return tick.label;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        labels: ['Volume', 'Manutenzione', 'Professionals', 'Materie', 'Cleaning'],
      },
      x1: {
        display: false,
        offset: true
      },
      y: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: 120000,
            beginAtZero: true,
            min: 0,
            grid: {
               drawOnChartArea: false
            }
          },
      y1: {
            suggestedMin: 0,
            suggestedMax: 1000000,
            beginAtZero: true,
            min: 0,
            position: 'right'
          }
      }
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much you are really helping me a lot! Now the only thing is the tooltip where it is written 0 instead of the x value.

Comment: Added in the previous snippet the tooltip part which is showing the label.

Comment: Love you so much <3