# chart js 3.9.1 - barchart - margin left

Tags: javascript, chart.js

how do i reduce the space between the bar and the y scale? I tried with padding but it doesn't work

Thanks

[image]

This is my configuration,I upload the data at runtime and update the graph

> Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

```
var options = {
    tooltips: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plugins:
    {
        datalabels:
        {
            color: 'white'
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'top', labels:
            {
                font: {size: 10},
                usePointStyle: true
            }
        }
    },
    scales:
    {
        x: {
            barPercentage: 6.5,
            categoryPercentage: 0.1
        },
        y: {
            barPercentage: 1,
            categoryPercentage: 1,
            beginAtZero: true,
            grace: '3%',
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
};


var barChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart3"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data:
    {
        labels: [""]
    },
    options:options
});

for (i = 0; i < parsed[0].length; i++)
{
    barChart.data.datasets.push({ label: parsed[0][i].label, backgroundColor: parsed[0][i].backgroundColor, data: ["" + parsed[0][i].data + ""], pointStyle:'circle' });
}

barChart.update();
```

Comment: Can you share the chart configuration (with data included)?

Comment: @user2057925 I've updated the post with the config code

Comment: have a look to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73333478/chartjs-multiple-datasets-but-with-single-bar-chart maybe can help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue sounds being related to `categoryPercentage` and `barPercentage` options that you are set in the axis but this is not the right place.

Move those options in the `chart.options` and it should work.

Try using `categoryPercentage: 1`.

```
var options = {
    categoryPercentage: 1,
    plugins:
    {
        datalabels:
        {
            color: 'white'
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'top', labels:
            {
                font: {size: 10},
                usePointStyle: true
            }
        }
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
       },
    },
    scales:
    {
        y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            grace: '3%',
        }
    }
};
```